# if a script that did MySQL LOCK TABLES table died before unlocking, what to do?

Tags: mysql

An instance of a script that did a MySQL

`LOCK TABLES` table

died by a bug, before it could do `UNLOCK TABLES`

Now I can't run that script anymore, it gets stuck waiting for the lock.

What to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this order the following commands:

```
mysql> show open tables where in_use > 0

mysql> show processlist

mysql> kill processid
```

Comment: I can do the first query. Don't have permissions for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process locks the table and then just kill it

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "wait" ? (or somewhat equivalent: kill the process to force session termination)

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html)

> If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session (transactional and nontransactional).

Comment: OK, this is something.  I thought, the process holding the lock is dead, and so, there is nothing to kill anymore,.  You are saying, that is not possible?